# Remove folders which include added files with ZipForge

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following files:

C:\item1\item11\item1.xls

C:\item1\item12\item11.xls

If I follow this code:

```
ZipForge zip = new ZipForge();            
try {               
 zip.FileName = Path.Combine( "C:\\" , "arch-01.zip");              

 zip.OpenArchive( System.IO.FileMode.Create );              

 zip.BaseDir = "C:\\"              

 zip.AddFiles( "C:\item1\item11\item1.xls");                            

 zip.AddFiles( "C:\item1\item12\item11.xls");                             

 zip.CloseArchive();             
} catch ( Exception e ) {              
Console.Write( e.Message );           
}
```

When opening ZIP file, I see one folder `item1`. If I open it, will see two folders `item11` and `item12` and in each of them will exists XLS file.

How to put directly in archive these files, means if I open ZIP file, I want to see these two files without navigating folders.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a "flat" zip file you have to set the `BaseDir` property of the `ZipForge` class
to the directory path where your files (to zip) are located.

The following example demonstrates this.

```
ZipForge zip = new ZipForge();

zip.FileName = Path.Combine("C:\\", "arch-01.zip");
zip.OpenArchive(System.IO.FileMode.Create);

zip.BaseDir = @"C:\item1\item11";
zip.AddFiles(@"C:\item1\item11\item1.xls");

zip.BaseDir = @"C:\item1\item12";
zip.AddFiles(@"C:\item1\item12\item11.xls");

zip.CloseArchive();
```

**BEGIN EDIT**

An alternative approach would be to use the StorePath enumeration of the ArchiverOptions class:

```
ZipForge zip = new ZipForge();

zip.FileName = Path.Combine("C:\\", "arch-01.zip");
zip.OpenArchive(System.IO.FileMode.Create);

// Set option to store no path.
zip.Options.StorePath = StorePathMode.NoPath;

zip.AddFiles(@"C:\item1\item11\item1.xls");    
zip.AddFiles(@"C:\item1\item12\item11.xls");

zip.CloseArchive();
```

**END EDIT**

Comment: That's no solution. I means that I want to see only files without navigating folders. Or, see one single folder which includes all files. (selected by me of course)

Comment: @MichaelSwan: Why? If I understand you correctly you are trying to create a zip file which does not contain folders. The code above creates a zip file with no folders.

Comment: @MichaelSwan: I've updated my answer to show an alternative approach.

Comment: That's the point ! Thank you. I forgot `Options` from that class :) Thanks. Upvote